# SHA-1 hash for HMAC Generated in Objective C and PHP (hash_hmac) dont match

Tags: php, objective-c, encoding, hmac, hmacsha1

I am trying to implement HMAC authentication from Objective C(CCHmac) and PHP (hash_hmac). I got the different hash result. Have anyone can help me? I don't know why to get the different hash result? Below is my Code (Objective-c & PHP) for your reference. Please!

PHP:

```
$APIConsumerSecret ="DcmzvkQC7Sno+lxnbDG0hTtZ0WTQn9T2T9DJxEmcB0";
$APIConsumerSecret = urlencode($APIConsumerSecret).'&';
$BaseString="GET&http%3A%2F%2Fboday.api.simppo.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_consumer_key%3DCN6W1I8E2CEWZJNQI2KA7KY3%26oauth_nonce%3DlxTSJL%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1357268295%26oauth_version%3D1.0";

echo base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1',$BaseString,$APIConsumerSecret,true));
```

PHP Result: `xJ5Ya4u4ghH4ugIieGIb9AcFpD0=`

Objective-C

```
- (NSString*)flickr_oauthSignatureFor:(NSString*)dataString withKey:(NSString*)secret
{
  NSData* secretData = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSData* stringData = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  const void* keyBytes = [secretData bytes];
  const void* dataBytes = [stringData bytes];

  ///#define CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH   20          /* digest length in bytes */
  void* outs = malloc(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH);

  CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, keyBytes, [secretData length], dataBytes, [stringData length], outs);

  // Soluion 1
  NSData* signatureData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:outs length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH freeWhenDone:YES];

  NSLog(@"D1-0: signatureData %@", signatureData );
  NSLog(@"base64:%@", [signatureData base64EncodedString] );

  return [signatureData base64EncodedString];
}
```

Objective-C Result:

```
D1-0: <59052771 e670a04b 3a2e87db 3d7965be 1aed112e>
base64: WQUnceZwoEs6LofbPXllvhrtES4=
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example php is URL encoding, the ObjectiveC is not.

Best to start with a simple example, short strings and skip the base64 encoding on both, Then compare results. When this works start adding the additional operations such as url encoding and base 64.

For php start with: echo hash_hmac('sha1', 'test string', 'secret'); and the same in objc.

Here is a starting point that matches php:

```
NSString* phpsignatureData = @"dd26bfddf122c1055d4cd5b054227727e1e3eecf";
NSLog(@"phpsignatureData: %@", phpsignatureData);

NSData* secretData = [@"secret" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData* stringData = [@"test string" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData *signatureData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, secretData.bytes, secretData.length, stringData.bytes, stringData.length, signatureData.mutableBytes);

NSLog(@"secretData %@", secretData );
NSLog(@"stringData %@", stringData );
NSLog(@"signatureData %@", signatureData );
```

NSLog output:

> ```
> phpsignatureData: dd26bfddf122c1055d4cd5b054227727e1e3eecf
> secretData <73656372 6574>   
> stringData <74657374 20737472 696e67>   
> signatureData <dd26bfdd f122c105 5d4cd5b0 54227727 e1e3eecf>
> ```

Comment: Hi Zaph, 
Thanks for your help, I follow your suggestion from the simple example(short strings and skip the base64 encoding). I got the root course that I lose one string "&" in my baseEncode string. So far, The output is correct, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:   (Objective C)

```
-(NSString *)DATA_TO_HeX_With_HmacDigestData:(NSData *)digestData{
    const unsigned char *dataBuffer = (const unsigned char *)[digestData bytes];
    NSUInteger          dataLength  = [digestData length];
    NSMutableString     *hexString  = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:(dataLength * 2)];
    for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; ++i)
    {
        [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", (unsigned int)dataBuffer[i]];
    }
    return [NSString stringWithString:hexString];
}

-(NSString *)HMAC_CREATOR:(NSString *)str andKeyData:(NSData *)keyData  {

    NSData *signatureData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH]={0};
    CCHmacContext context;
    CCHmacInit(&context, kCCHmacAlgSHA256, keyData.bytes, keyData.length);
    CCHmacUpdate(&context, signatureData.bytes, signatureData.length);
    CCHmacFinal(&context, digest);
    NSData *digestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:sizeof(digest)];
    return [self DATA_TO_HeX_With_HmacDigestData:digestData];
}
```